# Prove that for all $n \in Z^+$, Euclid’s algorithm applied to the pair $(f_{n+1}, f_{n+2})$, takes $n$ steps.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, euclidean-algorithm

Prove that for all $n \in Z^+$, Euclid’s algorithm applied to the pair $(f_{n+1}, f_{n+2})$, takes $n$ steps. (Here, as previously, $f_n$ denotes the nth Fibonacci number.)

I don't understand how to apply this algorithm with the use of actually numbers, and I tried to prove by induction, but was unsure as to how to do the inductive step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $f_{n+2} = f_{n+1} + f_n$ that defines Fibonacci numbers is the Euclidean division of $f_{n+2}$ by $f_{n+1}$ with remainder $f_n$.

The last step in Euclid’s algorithm is $f_3 = 2 f_2 + 0$, and so $n$ steps are taken.

Comment: This makes sense, but I don't understand how you would know that this is the nth step taken.

Comment: @user275237, one step for $f_k$, for $k=n+2, \dots, 3$, so $n$ steps.